# Match number before substring but not if it comes before a letter

Tags: php, regex

I've created a code to match gigabyte attribute in product descriptions. The problem is that it matches everything between [space] and 'GB' but I would like that it matches only numbers(and not letters or anything else) between space and 'GB'. Otherwise it should return nothing.

This is for All-import plugin for Wordpress.

```
//Extract gigabyte  

    function getFirstGB($str){

        //Remove space between numbers and GB
        $newString = str_replace(' GB', 'GB', $str);



        //Remove period in numbers
        $my = str_replace('.', '', $newString);

        if (preg_match("/(\d+)GB/", $my, $matches)) {
            $check = $matches[1];
        } else {
            $check = "";
        }
        if(strlen($check) < 10) {
            $media = $check;
        }
        else {
            $media = "";
        }
        //Add Gb only if it is not empty
        if (!empty($media)) {
            $island = $media . " Gb";
        }
        else {
        $island = "";
        }
            echo $island;
        }

        $media = "Samsung V7 V71700016GBD Memory";

        getFirstGB($media);
```

For the string: 'V7 V71700016GBD Memory Card'
I expect to be returned nothing
but it returns: 71700016 Gb

No problem for strings like that: "Sony 200GB MP3 10 Watt"
It returns what I wanted: 200 Gb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might add a space before your pattern `[ ](\d+)GB` or if the match could also occur at the start of the string, you could assert that what is on the left is not a non whitespace using `(?<!\S)`:

```
(?<!\S)(\d+)GB
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zRyFbG/1)

If GB can not be part of a longer word, you might add a word boundary `\b` at the end:

`(?<!\S)(\d+)GB\b`